# MenuItem binding to TabControl display horizontally

Tags: wpf, menuitem, tabcontrol

I want to bind part of `Menu` to a `TabControl`'s `TabItems` but have them display horizontally instead of a submenu.

Background: I can bind the `TabItem` of a `TabControl` into a `Menu` like this;

```
    <Style x:Key="TabMenuItem" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Header}" />
    <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Style>
....
<Menu >
    <MenuItem Header="My Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  >
        <MenuItem Header="Tabs" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyTabControl, Path=Items}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabMenuItem}" />
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem 2"/>
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem 3"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

This produces this:

[image]

What I want is it to look like this:

[image]

Tried doing this;

```
    <Menu  >
    <MenuItem Header="Tabs" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyTabControl, Path=Items}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabMenuItem}" >
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem 2"/>
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem 3"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

The returns the following message on run;

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

Comment: You cant set the `ItemsSource` **AND** add elements in XAML. To resolve your issue, you should flatten your Hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

A really ugly solution which needs heavy styling:

```
  <Menu>
     <MenuItem Header="Tabs"   >
         <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyTabControl, Path=Items}"/>
         <Separator></Separator>
         <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1"/>
         <MenuItem Header="SubItem 2"/>
         <MenuItem Header="SubItem 3"/>
     </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
```